# Add an object to a list within a method, no matter what type they are

Tags: c#, list, methods, parameter-passing, generic-list

i have to add an object to a list. but first, i have to check if that object (the object.name property) does already exist in the list and do some other tests. this all works fine, but i have to do it with different objects and their lists. so what i would like to have is a method, which takes the object and the list as parameters, and does all the magic, no matter of what type the object and the list is.

**what i have so far:**

the list and the object:

```
ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
private Product _newProduct = new Product();
public Product NewProduct
{
    get { return _newProduct; }
    set
    {
        if (_newProduct == value)
            return;
        _newProduct = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("NewProduct");
    }
}
```

searching if the object does exist:

```
bool productFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < ProductList.Count; i++)
{
    if (ProductList[i].Name == NewProduct.Name)
    {
        productFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

after some other tests, the object is added to the list:

```
ProductList.Add(NewProduct.Clone());
```

instead of writing that code for all my lists (5 different types), i would like to call a method and pass the object and the list. the method then performs the tests and adds the object to the list, no matter what type they are. how can i do this?

**i am looking for something like this:**

```
Save(NewProduct, ProductList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an interface and implement it in all entities you need:

```
interface INamedEntity : ICloneable
{
    stirng Name { get; }
}

class Product : INamedEntity { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can re-write code like this:

```
void Save<T>(List<T> entities, T entity)
    where T: INamedEntity
{
    // searching if the object does exist:
    var isExists = entities.Any(e => e.Name == entity.Name);

    // after some other tests, the object is added to the list:
    entities.Add(entity.Clone());
}
```

Comment: that does shorten my search code, but it does not answer my question? i am looking for a way to add an object to a list. but i have to do it with different objects and their lists. so i would like to have a method doing it. otherwise i have to copy a lot of code for each case.

Comment: i get an error: `ObservableCollection` has no implementation of `Any`

Comment: That's true - it is an extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1. You have to type `using System.Linq` in usings list.

Answer (score 1):

you could use an interface which has the common properties and methods

```
interface IItem
{
    public string Name {set; get;}
}
```

then your classes should implement the interface, for example

```
class Product: Item { ...}
```

Now you can use the following general method to save the items

```
public void Save(IItem item, List<IItem> list)
{

    if (!list.Any(x => x.Name == item.Name))
       list.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: could you post a simple example?

Comment: @el-nino, I gave an example in my answer